# Scale ticks of a LogLinear Plot

Tags: plotting, ticks

I have LogLinear plots for which I want to scale the ticks on the x-axis. The following MWE, which works for the linear plot is showing ticks at the wrong positions for the LogLinear plot

```
Clear[plot];

plot = LogLinearPlot[Erf[x], {x, 1, 100}]
scalefact= 10^(-10);
newticks = {#, scalefact #} & /@ Range[1, 100];
Show[plot, Ticks -> {newticks, Automatic}]
```

[image: plot1]

[image: plot2]

Since I already have the plots I would not like to scale the x-axis, I just want to change the tick specifications. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can take x-`Ticks` from `plot` either with:

```
oldticks = Charting`ScaledTicks[{Log, Exp}][Log@1, Log@100, {6,6}]
```

or with:

```
oldticks = (Ticks /. AbsoluteOptions[plot, Ticks])[[1]]
```

Now change labels:

```
Show[plot, 
 Ticks -> {oldticks /. {a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ, c__} :> {a, scalefact b, c}, 
  Automatic}]
```

[image]

**EDIT**

To answer new request in comment about having only specific ticks:

```
newTicks = {Log[#], scalefact #} & /@ {1., 10., 100.}
newTicksEmpty = {Log[#], Spacer[0]} & /@ {1., 10., 100.}
Show[plot, 
 FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {newTicks, newTicksEmpty}}, 
  Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Minor ticks can be added with `Subdivide` of the corresponding interval and using technique as for `newTicksEmpty`:

```
minor = {Log@#, Spacer[0], {0.005, 0}} & /@ 
 Join[Subdivide[1, 10., 9], Subdivide[10, 100., 9]]

Show[plot, 
 FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {Join[newTicks, minor], 
    Join[newTicksEmpty, minor]}}, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The Charting`ScaledTIcks works for me. Just another related query. How do I control the positioning of the major and minor ticks. For instance, in the above example I want the ticks to appear only at 10^(-10), 10^(-9) and 10^(-8).

Comment: Please, see my edit.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Thank you once again.

Comment: Glad to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
newticks = Map[{#, # *1.*10^-10} &, Range[1, 100]];
```

which only differs from your definition by a factor `1.`.

Have fun!